# Show A dialouge when app starts and Fix a Navigation Drawer issue

Tags: java, android

I have created a `AlertDialogue`. I want that when I open the App Dialogue will Show. Which method should I try? I tried `onStart` method but its doesn't works.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart(); AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setTitle("Quiz");
        builder.setMessage("Are You Sure?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ok was Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ok was Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                });
    }
```

On the Navigation Drawer I called a method . That method is created with a Alert Dialouge . When i click the item in Navigation Drawer its Shows 3-4 times continuously. i want that it will show only one time .

here is the code :

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

 if (id == R.id.con_id) {

            convertPointsToMoney();
}
  DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;    
}
```

I want to add a Facebook group link on the navigation item. When I click on that item the browser will open and show the site.

Comment: For the issue related to `AlertDialogue` try the code in onCreate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `AlertDialogue`inside `onCreate()`